# Proteins with one SS bond?

Tags: bioinformatics, protein-database

I would like to find proteins with exactly one SS bond? Is there a database where I can search this?
I've tried advanced search on https://www.rcsb.org/, but no such option, at least i could not find it.

Comment: This is the wrong site for this question look at https://biology.stackexchange.com/ for help with biology problems

Comment: or even better, https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh, thanks. I didn't quite know how these stack-sites differ.